# Using Policies in Laravel 5.5.14

Tags: api, authorization, laravel-5.5, policies

I am new in using policies in Laravel. I am learning API Development using Laravel. My codes are as bellows.

**TopicPolicy.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Topic;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class Topicpolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, Topic $topic)
    {
        return $user->ownsTopic($topic);
    }

    public function destroy(User $user, Topic $topic)
    {
        return $user->ownsTopic($topic);
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```

**TopicController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Topic;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreTopicRequest;
use App\Transformers\TopicTransformer;
use League\Fractal\Pagination\IlluminatePaginatorAdapter;

class TopicController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Topic $topic) {
        $this->authorize('destroy',$topic);
        $topic->delete();
        return response(null,204);
    }
}
```

I am getting error `This action is unauthorized.`. I don't know how to use  policies. Could anyone guide me to use policies in Laravel 5.5.14 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the AuthServiceProvider class you have to register the policy in the policies aray. Laravel documents is a good place to [start](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#registering-policies)

```
protected $policies = [
  \App\Topic::class => \App\Policies\Topicpolicy::class 
]
```

Second obtain a personal token from your app so you can use it to make calls to your api. You use passport and passport comes with ready to use Vue components to help you start.If you want to consume the api inside the same application check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

I am not sure what you try to accomplice with the HandlesAuthorization trait inside the policy. Laravel has a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#via-middleware) for this reason for us to use.